# Populate TreeView from another class (or something better?) C#

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I'm trying to make a level reader application for one of my favourite games, and simply put this is what I'm trying to achieve currently:

First 8 bytes of level file:

```
0100000001000000
```

It states that the mesh version = 1 and vertex version = 1.

I've made a GUI in which I have a treeview, and in the tree it has header, and in header it has vertex and mesh version. I would like to populate these with this data.

Now this is where my first problem arises:
I want to have all my reading done in its own class (for example, HeaderData, MaterialData), etc, just to make the code cleaner.
Because I'm doing this in another class, 
I have NO idea how I can access my treeview from said class (if I were in the Form class I could just do treeView1.whatever, but I don't know how to access it from another class. 
Note: I've tried Levelreader.Form1.treeView1, but it doesn't exist).

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            textBox1.Text = fileDialog.FileName;
            using (BinaryReader fileBytes = new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(textBox1.Text))))
            {
                //Get the hex data in bytearray format
                //This won't be displayed
                int length = (int)fileBytes.BaseStream.Length;
                byte[] hex = fileBytes.ReadBytes(length);
                //File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\temp_file.txt", hex);

                //This is what's displayed.
                //Remember to make changes to the byte array
                //and then update the view.
                string tempStr = BitConverter.ToString(hex).Replace("-", " ");
                richTextBox1.Text = tempStr;
                richTextBox1.ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.ForcedVertical;

                //Instantiate the class
                Header temp = new Header();
                temp.HeaderData(hex);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

This is the method, within the class Form1, in namespace LevelReader, that reads the file and then instantiates the class Header(). I then call HeaderData, and within that class I get the mesh and vertex version.

```
namespace SceneStuff
{
    public class Header
    {

        public void HeaderData(byte[] hex)
        {
            //First 4 Bytes = Mesh Version
            //Second 4 Bytes = Vertex Version
            byte[] meshVersion = hex.Take(4).ToArray();
            byte[] vertexVersion = hex.Skip(4).Take(4).ToArray();

        }

    }
}
```

in THIS method is where I want to use this data to populate my treeview. And say for example I changed some information in the level, such as changing the mesh version to 2, I want, when I press 'Compile Level' (in my apps GUI) to read from the TreeView, as I believe it would be best that way. However, if you have suggestions, please state them, as I'm new to c#!


So in summary, here are my two problems:
1) How can I access my treeview from another namespace/class?
2) Do you have any suggestions to improve my code? (and the way I plan to compile my levels?)

Thanks!

P.S. I apologize for the wall of text! >_<

**Edit:**

I have another problem which is that I can't seem to populate my node.

It is created like this:

```
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode treeNode2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode("Mesh Version");
```

and below:

```
        treeNode2.Name = "meshVersion";
        treeNode2.Text = "Mesh Version";
```

I've tried adding treeNode2 as a reference to my method, but that doesn't work.
I've tried to select it with `treeView1.SelectedNode = treeView1.Nodes[1].Nodes[1];` but that doesn't seem to work either. 
(here is an image of the GUI, which shows that `Nodes[1].Nodes[1]` is, I think, what I'm trying to access (I'm trying to access Mesh Version) https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8bGg.png

So what I need to do is to access that PRE EXISTING NODE and add a child to it. I just can't seem to find any tutorials that detail it in these circumstances and I don't understand it will enough to cater their tutorials to suit my needs.

Thanks so much.

Comment: @Saeid87 well, I'm new to c# so I thought the way to reference it was "Levelreader.Form1.treeView1.dostuff", in the form1 class "treeView1.dostuff" works. But outside of the class it says it doesn't exist.
Can you please clarify?

Comment: The Mesh Version Node is `treeView1.Nodes[1].Nodes[0].Nodes[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Three Solutions :

1. You could change the visibility of the TreeView in `Form1.Designer.cs` to `public` or `internal`
2. Or you could build the TreeView Nodes inside the `HeaderData()` function and return them.
3. Or as @[Saeid87](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436802/populate-treeview-from-another-class-or-something-better-c-sharp/12437716#comment16722947_12436802) said, you could pass the TreeView by reference the `HeaderData()` function:

**Example :**

```
public void HeaderData(byte[] hex, ref TreeView treeview)
{
    //First 4 Bytes = Mesh Version
    //Second 4 Bytes = Vertex Version
    byte[] meshVersion = hex.Take(4).ToArray();
    byte[] vertexVersion = hex.Skip(4).Take(4).ToArray();
    
    //Example: Do something with the Mesh Version Node
    treeView1.Nodes[1].Nodes[0].Nodes[0].Text = "Lorem ipsum";
}
```

and When you call your function pass the TreeView by reference (inside your `button1_Click` function)

```
temp.HeaderData(hex, ref treeView1)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I'm trying to find some code that allows the population of nodes that are pre-existing; that is, nodes that have been created already in the designer view. All of the tutorials I seem to find entail creating a node inside the method you're working from, which isn't what I want to do. Hence I can't seem to find a way to populate a pre-existing node. If possible I'll update my question, and if you would, could you please show me how to populate the node? Thanks.